# Nuxt - How to copy icons to dist folder?

Tags: webpack, nuxt.js

I have a set of images which have to served from dist/_nuxt/ root folder. If I add them in static, the build copies them to dist/_nuxt/static/. How can I copy this image folder to dist/_nuxt/img/ ?

Comment: are you making spa application?

Comment: Yes it is currently in SPA format. Does that change anything?